# Calculus chain rule clarification

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

[Chain rule clarification:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyYP0.png)
[image]

Please have a look at the picture before continuing to read my query as this picture provides the context. On the fourth line of working (the one before the final simplified answer), could I get some clarification on the use of chain rule here?

Referring to the line above this one, $d/dt(df/dg) x dg/dt = dg/dt x d/dg(df/dg) x dg/dt$ (ignoring the part on the right of the addition). Does this mean $d/dt(df/dg) = dg/dt x d/dg(df/dg)$ since $dg/dt x d/dg = d/dt$ with the $dg$ cancelling out on the LHS. Since I have never come across this in my life, could someone please explain this is some depth if what I wrote here is true. If false could someone give me an explanation of the working. Sorry in advance if my English is not clear as it is not my native language.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's a link to a guide on how to typeset a question properly in LaTeX http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. I'd suggest that you take sometime to edit your question to a more readable form.

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter important parts of your question as text instead of posting a picture of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in question summaries. The previous comment has a link to a quick reference for formatting mathematical expressions in MathJax.

Comment: Please, please, please format the expressions in your last paragraph properly. They’re night unreadable. Make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.